# How do I add Median to this query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to add median to the following query, the median obviously will for each type of bedroom, unittypeid (already in the group by), I tried working with PERCENTILE_CONT but I couldnt figure out how to make it work.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempListings
(
    ListingId int,
    Price money,
    UnitTypeId int,
    BedroomsAvailable int
)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(1, 1000, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(2, 2000, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(3, 3000, 1, 1)

INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(4, 1000, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(5, 2000, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(6, 3000, 1, 2)

INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(7, 1000, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(8, 2000, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(9, 3000, 2, 1)

INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(10, 1000, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(11, 2000, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(12, 3000, 2, 2)
  
SELECT BedroomsAvailable, 
    COUNT(listingid) AS Count, 
    MIN(price) AS MinPrice, 
    MAX(price) AS MaxPrice, 
    AVG(price) AS AveragePrice,
    STDEV(price) as StandardDeviation,
    UnitTypeId
FROM #TempListings
GROUP BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId
ORDER BY UnitTypeId

DROP TABLE #TempListings
```

I am using sqlserver 2019 if it matters

Comment: SQL Server 2022 has a new aggregate function [`approx_percentile_cont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/approx-percentile-cont-transact-sql) which can be used (with parameter 0.5) to calculate an _approximate_ median without needing to use a CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted inly explained how the syntax works.
But as complete Query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #TempListings
> (
>     ListingId int,
>     Price money,
>     UnitTypeId int,
>     BedroomsAvailable int
> )
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(1, 1000, 1, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(2, 2000, 1, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(3, 3000, 1, 1)
>
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(4, 1000, 1, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(5, 2000, 1, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(6, 3000, 1, 2)
>
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(7, 1000, 2, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(8, 2000, 2, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(9, 3000, 2, 1)
>
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(10, 1000, 2, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(11, 2000, 2, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(12, 3000, 2, 2)
>
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(13, 5000, 2, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(14, 6000, 2, 1)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(15, 7000, 2, 1)
>
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(16, 8000, 2, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(17, 9000, 2, 2)
> INSERT INTO #TempListings VALUES(18, 10000, 2, 2)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH #myselect
>  AS (SELECT 
>          BedroomsAvailable
>          ,ListingId 
>          ,UnitTypeId
>          ,Price,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price)  
>          OVER (PARTITION BY UnitTypeId) AS MedianCont
>     FROM #TempListings)
> SELECT BedroomsAvailable 
>     ,COUNT(listingid) AS Count 
>     ,MIN(price) AS MinPrice 
>     ,MAX(price) AS MaxPrice 
>     ,AVG(price) AS AveragePrice
>     ,STDEV(price) as StandardDeviation 
>     , MIN(MedianCont) MedianCont
>     ,UnitTypeId
> FROM #myselect
> GROUP BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId
> ORDER BY UnitTypeId   
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> BedroomsAvailable | Count |  MinPrice |   MaxPrice | AveragePrice | StandardDeviation | MedianCont | UnitTypeId
> ----------------: | ----: | --------: | ---------: | -----------: | ----------------: | ---------: | ---------:
>                 1 |     3 | 1000.0000 |  3000.0000 |    2000.0000 |              1000 |       2000 |          1
>                 2 |     3 | 1000.0000 |  3000.0000 |    2000.0000 |              1000 |       2000 |          1
>                 1 |     6 | 1000.0000 |  7000.0000 |    4000.0000 |  2366.43191323985 |       4000 |          2
>                 2 |     6 | 1000.0000 | 10000.0000 |    5500.0000 |  3937.00393700591 |       4000 |          2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d1b8f50c0461795f45b3201297f5c15)*

Answer (score 2):

There's a multitude of ways to calculate the Median in SQL Server.
Aaron Bertrand goes through the main ones and compares their performance in [What Is The Fastest Way To Calculate The Median?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median).

If you want to use PERCENTILE_COUNT you can do it this way:

```
SELECT BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) AS PriceMedian
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) OVER (PARTITION BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId)
FROM #TempListings
```

You can then join this back to your main query on `BedroomsAvailable` and `UnitTypeId`.

E.g:

```
WITH CTE_PriceMedians AS
(
    SELECT BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) AS PriceMedian
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) OVER (PARTITION BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId)
    FROM #TempListings
)

SELECT BedroomsAvailable 
    ,COUNT(listingid) AS Count 
    ,MIN(price) AS MinPrice 
    ,MAX(price) AS MaxPrice 
    ,AVG(price) AS AveragePrice
    ,STDEV(price) as StandardDeviation 
    ,MIN(MedianCont) MedianCont
    ,UnitTypeId
    ,PriceMedian
    ,SUM(price)/COUNT(1) AS PriceMean
FROM #TempListings AS TL
INNER JOIN CTE_PriceMedians AS PM
    ON TL.BedroomsAvailable = PM.BedroomsAvailable
    AND TL.UnitTypeId = PM.UnitTypeId
GROUP BY BedroomsAvailable, UnitTypeId
ORDER BY UnitTypeId
```